# Prevent last (fluid) column from dropping down on browser resize?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have layout like this:

```
/*Sidebar*/ /*Column1*/ /*Column2*/ /*Column3*/ /*Sidebar*/
```

So now I want to make a fluid layout, when looking on desktop computer it looks good but the problem comes when viewing on reduced window (Ipad) so it look like this:

```
/*Sidebar*/ /*Column1*/ /*Column2*/ /*Sidebar*/ 
            /*Column3*/
```

My css:

```
#blogwrapper {
background-color:#F2F2F2;
margin:0 auto;
max-width: 56%; 
}

.sidebar_sec {
width:21%;
float: left;
}

#blogs_three_cols .left_column {
float:left;
width: 32.7%;
}

#blogs_three_cols .middle_column {
float:left;
margin-left:0.5em;
width: 32.7%;   
}

#blogs_three_cols .right_column {   
margin-left:0.5em;
width: 32.7%;
float:left;
}
```

You can see the problem [HERE](http://www.vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/three-cols-2/) (Try to reduce browser size).

So my question is how can I prevent my last column from dropping down when resizing my browser window? Thank you!

Comment: The simple answer is the content in your `li`s are too long for the dimensions you set, hence it wraps onto the next line.

Comment: My real problem are the columns...not menu...

Comment: It's still the same problem, the column widths are too wide including the margin padding etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `margin-left` on your middle and right columns to use `%` rather than `em`, with the values being equal to 100 - total widths of the three divs (0.95% in this case)

```
#blogs_three_cols .middle_column {
float:left;
margin-left: 0.95%;
width: 32.7%;   
}

#blogs_three_cols .right_column {   
margin-left: 0.95%;
width: 32.7%;
float:left;
}
```